# MySQL compare data from date ranges prior to the current row and count() them

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

This is in reference to the still-open question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093490/mysql-subquery-with-user-defined-variables) - I want to try to approach it differently.

I have a MySQL table with two pieces of information: `order_date` and `email_address`. This is exhaustive and non-distinct, meaning that there are duplicates if someone happened to make more than one purchase per-day.

I need to get the following report in as few queries as possible, hopefully one:

```
YYYY-MM | number_emails_this_month | numer_emails_repeated_prior
```

Where some sample output from the query result would look like this:

```
YYYY-MM | number_emails_this_month | numer_emails_repeated_prior
2010-02     23423               1231
2010-03     4422                2234
2010-04     1424                650
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That is sample output, not sample data correct?

Comment: Correct, sorry - will correct the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in a subsequent related question here:

[MySQL Subquery with User-Defined Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093490/mysql-subquery-with-user-defined-variables)

Ultimately the solution was to create a table with the ranges as-requested and join on that instead of using a subquery to define the ranges in question. In retrospect, use of the user-defined vars in MySQL aided the search for the subquery-less solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what is `number_emails_repeated_prior`. If you could post a short example of data and a corresponding example of wanted results it would be helpful.

Taking a guess about what you are aiming for, to get the number of emails from a specific user per month all you need is:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y-%m') as `YYYY-MM`, 
       COUNT(email_address) as `number_emails_this_month `
FROM table_name
WHERE email_address = 'some@address'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: The question is asking how do i combine your query, *and* the count of the people from within that query versus any other previous month, returning only the count of those that intersect.

Comment: Also, if you see the outstanding question referenced at the top - you'll see the sample data you request...